# I want a fan-out ingress in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I want to create an ingress resource with two services!
first one is customer which is working like this `http://customer.svc/api/v1/customer/docs/`
second is auth which is working like this `http://auth.svc/docs`

I want a ingress resource `api.xyz.com` with below fan-out
`api.xyz.com/customer -> redirects to customer svc`
`api.xyz.com/auth -> redirscts to auth svc`

below is my ingress resource but it doesn't work

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: api-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
spec:
  rules:
  - host: api.xyz.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /customer
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: nova-be-customer-svc
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /auth
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: identity-auth-server-svc
            port:
              number: 80
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - api.xyz.com
    secretName: api-tls
```

Comment: I found this documentation on how to create a [fanout](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#simple-fanout) which you can use as a guidance. From this concern, can you describe your ingress to check if the fanout you made will appear. When you mentioned its not working how did you test the fanout you create and what are the error messages that you are getting.